# render a flask MultipleSelectField with selected values highlighted

Tags: javascript, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

In my flask app, I need to **render a form that has a MultipleSelectField with some already selected options**. I have done this successfully but the problem is that **they are not highlighted** and thus the **user can't know which options are already selected** which can also enable them be deselected.
Any ideas on how I can get this done from the backend or even using vanilla javascript.
Here is the view function that renders the form:

```
@home.route('/edit/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit_post(id):
    post = Post.query.get_or_404(id)
    if current_user != post.author and not current_user.can(Permission.ADMINISTER):
        abort(403)
    form = PostForm()
    form.tag.choices = [(tag.id, tag.name) for tag in Tag.query.order_by('name')]
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        post.body = form.body.data
        posttags = db.session.query(categories).filter_by(post_id=id).all()
        for id in form.tag.data:
            if (post.id, id) not in posttags:
                post.tags.append(Tag.query.get(id))
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('.view_post', id=post.id))
    form.body.data = post.body
    # already selected values
    form.tag.data = [tag_id for tag_id in db.session.query(categories).filter_by(post_id=post.id).all()]
    return render_template('home/edit_post.html', form=form, title='Edit Post')
```

Have done some research. So, in a nutshell, how can I add the **selected** attribute to the pre-selected options.

Comment: Please provide some source code?

Comment: have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519729/wtforms-how-to-select-options-in-selectmultiplefield