# Flask WTForms_SQLAlchemy and populating selected on choice SelectMultipleField

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Using Flask with WTForms and SQLAlchemy to try and make life easier for what should be a simple test recording tool, but I've been stuck and at this point for a while and not getting anywhere with searching. I'm at the point of just want to code up the form myself, so I'm hopeful for a second look.  I've tried to knock this down to just the relevant parts of the code.

Blank forms save fine, edits save fine, but in edit mode the SelectMultipleField will not show selected the values that were returned by the SQLAlchemy query result (all other fields are fine and do populate). Using a print() in the python, I can see the saved values are returning from the Query.

The only thing that I can think of is that the SelectMultipleField is defined with empty choices but the choices ares then populated after class instantiation, but before the form is rendered. Not finding anything that indicates a different way to do this... but I can say that QuerySelectMultipleField won't work for me because of how I have to build the active test list.

Using:

```
Package            Version
------------------ -------
Flask              1.1.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy   2.4.4
Flask-WTF          0.14.3
Jinja2             2.11.3
pysqlite3          0.4.5
SQLAlchemy         1.3.23
Werkzeug           1.0.1
WTForms            2.3.3
WTForms-SQLAlchemy 0.3
```

I have my form definition:

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    rep_name = StringField(
        'Tester\'s Name',
        validators=[validators.InputRequired(), validators.Length(max=50)]
    )
    notes = TextAreaField(
        'Notes',
        validators=[validators.Length(max=255)]
    )

    supported_tests = SelectMultipleField(
        'Supported Tests',
        choices = [],
        validators=[validators.InputRequired()]
    )
```

My db model:

```
class SupportedTests(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'supportedtestlkup'
    test = db.Column(db.String(64), primary_key=True)
    tester_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('testers.id'), nullable=False, primary_key=True)

class Testers(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'testers'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    rep_name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    notes = db.Column(db.String(255))
    supported_tests = db.relationship("SupportedTests", backref=db.backref("supportedtestlkup", order_by=id), cascade="all, delete-orphan", lazy=True)
```

My flask app:

```
@app.route('/setup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def doSetup():

    Entry = dal.Testers.query.get(int(EditID))
    Form = forms.MyForm(request.form, obj=Entry)
    Form.supported_tests.choices = get_active_tests()
...
    print('Entry.Tests =', Entry.supported_tests )
    return render_template(
        'setup.html',
        form=Form,
    )
```

Looking at the HTML output, the MultiSelect value does match the values in the list that python prints.

```
<select class="form-control" id="supported_tests" multiple name="supported_tests" required size="10">
<option value="1.5">Test Five</option>

Entry.Tests = [1.0, 1.2, 1.5]
```

Thoughts appreciated...

**-- Update --**

Rethinking this, I may just be missing is how to properly fill the Form.supported_tests.choices... If I try to use the SupportedTests object to fill the choices, I get an error "cannot unpack non-iterable" so it doesn't take that.  If I use a list of (value, name) for choices, then I get "'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'".

I have tried to add a loop on the Form.supported_tests.data to put the data into SupportedTests class instances, and this kinda works... but I'm back to not having anything selected when you go to the form.

Overwriting the Form.supported_tests.data does get me the fields selected on the form, but then the edit of the form never saves any changes because forcing Form.supported_tests.data overwrites anything incoming from request.form.

Comment: Yes, the options are showing in HTML.  See the last code block above where I copied the first option from the HTML and the python print output.  The values match, so I would expect it to be selected...  (note: edited the HTML for readability) Thanks!

Comment: Ok, have you tried `form.supported_tests.data = <your_value_to_be_selected>`?

Comment: Ah, good thought.  Printing Form.supported_tests.data resulted in an empty list.  So I just tried to set Form.supported_tests.data = Entry.supported_tests.  Printing Form.supported_tests.data now returns the values, but no effect on the HTML.

Comment: Hi Patrick, you have me on the right track... If I manually create a list of strings, now I get them selected.  Form.supported_tests.data = ["1.0", "1.2", "1.5"]  So they seem to be hung up on the datatype.

Comment: Ok, so this isn't quite the solution.  If I modify the "Form.supported_tests.data" element, changes are not saving.

Comment: What I do in my app, is only prefill the form field data if the `request.method == 'GET'`, otherwise, I check for the form submit and don't worry about prefilling it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5519729/15368978) question might also help you.

Comment: Hi Patrick,  so I need to prefill the form data even on posts, but I can add a form submit check as an if condition for rewriting Form.supported_tests.data... This is working for now, but does still feel kludgy.  I do think I need to properly see how to populate the Form.supported_tests.choices with the SQLAlchemy data objects and likely that is the key of my trouble.  -- Many thanks!